# Can I force my angular directive to add its template as a sibling to the directive element?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I want to create an attribute-only directive that turns the element into a trigger for showing a sibling element. Here's a simplified example:

```
<button show-box>Click Me</button>
```

I want the `showBox` directive to create a hidden `<div>` element next to the button and attach a click event to the button.

```
app.directive('showBox', function () {
    return {
        template: '<div ng-show="boxVisible"><more-directives></more-directives></div>',
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
            scope.boxVisible = false;
            element.click(function () {
                scope.$apply(function () {
                    scope.boxVisible = true;
                });
            });
        })
    };
});
```

However, I can only seem to get my directive to replace the whole button element (`replace: true`) with my directive template or nest the template within the button itself (`replace: false`).

I suppose I could omit the template and just do it JQuery style by attaching a click event to `element` and adding some markup using `element.after` but I wondered if there was a more official "angular way" to accomplish this. Plus, in the sibling element I am using additional directives and will have to manually compile the markup if I do it that way and it seems a little hackish.

I don't know much about angular transclusion and was about to start going down that road to see if it does anything related to what I'm trying to do or not but I figured I'd ask here first.

Any ideas on how I might go about creating such a directive?

Comment: Show some code; please..   I think you need to look at transclude.

Comment: My limited understanding of transclude tells me that only the contents within the element that the directive is attached to will be "transcluded" into the directive template, yes? Or is there a way to preserve the parent element?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this by modifying the compile function of your directive:

```
app.directive('showBox', function() {
  return {
    compile: function(iElem) {

      // append whatever html you want here
      iElem.after('<div ng-show="boxVisible">derp</div>');

      // return the linking function from the compile function
      return function(scope, element, attr) {
        scope.boxVisible = false;
        element.on('click', function() {
          scope.$apply(function() {
            scope.boxVisible = !scope.boxVisible;
          });
        });
      };
    }
  };
});
```

I'm not sure if you'll need to `$compile` the content as well - if directives inside the `iElem.after()` template don't work then have a look into that.

[Here's a plunker to demonstrate it working.](http://plnkr.co/edit/0iXHyTEIDWsdn6iof4q3?p=preview)

Comment: Thanks! PS - It does need `$compile`d :) http://codepen.io/Chevex/pen/JIvoA?editors=001

Comment: What if we don't want to load sibling template asynchronously? How would we handle that? Should we manually access template or could we still utilize `templateUrl` somehow?

Comment: @RobertKoritnik - not sure what you mean, sorry.

Comment: Well in your case you've defined your sibling content statically, but as this HTML content can be rather verbose and it's good to separate different things I'd like to have it in a separate HTML file. Directives usually utilize `templateUrl` to separately load the template and then compile. In this case we'd likely need to manually do that using `$http` service... What I was asking is whether we can still somehow utilize `templateUrl` in our directive and have it added as sibling content?